# Format Dictionary Key:Value on a New Line and New Tab

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, formatting

I'm running python v2.7.

I've a `defaultdict(int)` that I extract keys and values from, and then write to an output file using string formatting. My code to write to the file looks like this:

```
output_line = '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(a, b, c, d, e)
output_file.write(output_line)
```

a, b, c, etc. are values that come from this `defaultdict(int)`, let's call it `old_dict`. I write to the file in a `for` loop for every key in the `old_dict`, and thus far I'm satisfied with the output; it gives me essentially a table, where each column is separated by tabs (a tab-delineated file which I can open in Excel).

The problem I'm running into is that I create another dictionary based on the first `defaultdict(int)`, and I want to output that dictionary's `key: value` pair **in between** one of the columns. The kicker is that I'd like for the `key: value` pair to be printed **vertically**, not horizontally (because this second dictionary can be massive, and if I wrote it horizontally, then I'd have to scroll really, really far to see every `key: value`!)

Example code:

```
old_dict = defaultdict(int)
new_dict = old_dict[same_key]  # Lookup "same_key" in old_dict, get all associated nested matching key: values, and store in "new_dict"
nicer_format = ", ".join("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in new_dict.items())  # Clean up the format a bit for writing to file.
```

So now when I change `output_line` to:

```
output_line = '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(a, b, c, nicer_format, d, e)
```

It works, but I get a **horizontal** list (i.e. nicer_format is horizontal). The output looks something like:
[Undesired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvwNn.png)

What I'd like to see is content under Column Header 4 be displayed vertically:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7B3K.png)

I've tried string formatting my `join` statement under `nicer_format` variable, based on what I read under the "Padding and aligning strings" section [here](https://pyformat.info/). Something like

`nicer_format = ", ".join("{}: {}{":\t>3"}".format(k, v) for k, v in new_dict.items())`

Since I want to separate each new value by three tabs and a new line. However, this fails.

I've also tried toying with pandas, and using this line of code:

```
import pandas as pd
test_panda = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient="index")
```

I'm unsure what `orient="index"` is supposed to be (I've only just started messing with pandas, and haven't read any documentation on this argument), but I get the following output:

[Output after using pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3obYM.png)

It's close, since now the output is vertical, but it's not under the right column! Is there a way to get the output to go under Column Header 4? Do I even need pandas for this? What was wrong with my string padding/formatting attempt above?

EDIT: I've tried creating my MCV code from scratch, but I'm getting an error when trying to reconstruct my dictionaries now, and I don't know how to fix it. I think this is because in my real code, I build my dictionaries from reading 2 files as `defaultdict(int)`, and it works fine. I can attach those files if needed, but until then, here's my MCV code built from scratch to try to illustrate a little more detail.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd

dict_one, dict_intermediate = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)), defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))


# This is where my dictionaries get messed up. Normally I iterate through the file(s) and build them as defaultdict(int).
# But I don't know how to change that here, so I just manually wrote out here what the keys and values should be.
# The values are the (int) part; it's a set of that keeps track how many times each string appears.
# value_one and value_two are the final values after I finish reading the files and have the dictionaries completed.
key_one = "ACGACGGGCACT\tGAGCACCAGGAGCCGCGTGCCTGGCCCGAAGTACTGGGTCTCTTGAAAGCCCCCGCTATTGCTGCTGGCACAGAAGTACACAGCTGAGTCCCTGGGTTCT\tCASSNSGGFQETQYF\t8\t9"  # UMI with other extra info
value_one = "{'B670': 1, 'B180': 1, 'B240': 1, 'B360': 1, 'B880': 1, 'B210': 1, 'B230': 1, 'B500': 1, 'B480': 1}"  # Batch number: count

key_two = "ACGACGGGCACT"  # This is the UMI.
value_two = "{CTGGGGTGACCCCCCCAAGAACTGATCATAACGTACTCTGCGTTGATACCACTAAGGCTGGAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACATCT: 1," \
            "CTGGGGTGACCCCCCCAAGAACTGATCATAACGTACTCTGCGTTGATACCACTGAGGCTGGAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACATCT: 1," \
            "CTGGGGTGACCCCCCCAAGAACTGATCATAACGTACTCTGCGTTGATACCACTGAGGCTGGGAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACATCT: 1," \
            "CTGGGGTGACTCCCCCAAGAACTGATCATAACGAACTCTGCGTTGATACCACTGAGGCTGGAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACATCT: 1}"  # Sequence: count

dict_one[key_one] += value_one
dict_intermediate[key_two] += value_two

def split_tabs(x):
    """
    Function to split tab-separated strings. It's used to break up the keys and values
    into their individual components.
    """
    return x.split('\t')


for k in dict_one:
    umi = split_tabs(k)[0]  # Extract the UMI from the key.
    overlap_reads = int(split_tabs(k)[4])  # Extract the reads from the key.
    dict_two = dict_intermediate[umi]  # Lookup the matching UMI in "dict_intermediate" & get all sequences + their counts in "dict_two".
    source_sequences = ", ".join("{}: {}".format(a, b) for a, b in dict_two.items())  # Output all sequences + their counts associated with that UMI (format as "sequence: count").
    panda_test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_one, orient="index")

    batch_set = ", ".join("{}: {}".format(a, b) for a, b in dict_one[key_one].items())
    total_counts = sum(dict_two.values())  # Sum of counts for all sequences for a single UMI.
    earliest_batch = min(dict_one[k].keys())  # The smallest batch (B) number.

    output_line = '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(k, panda_test, batch_set, total_counts, earliest_batch)
```

Comment: Your desired and undesired output have 4 cols but your example code has 6

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @nog642 Right, I just truncated my images to 4 columns to illustrate my point, but there are additional columns after them.

Comment: @Prune I added my MCV code as best I could. I wrote it from scratch; since I build my `defaultdicts` from 2 files, I tried to avoid that in my rewritten code.

Comment: Your posted code still fails to compile: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'collections.defaultdict' and 'str'**

Comment: @Prune Right, that's what I was referring to in my comment block above key_one. I'm somewhat new-ish to Python, so I'm not able to build my 2 dictionaries from the code I wrote from scratch, but I AM able to build them from the 2 files I have. Maybe I'm overlooking something. But that's why I just wrote what I expect each key and each value to be in each dictionary once they're compiled.

Regardless, I believe I got a suitable solution using something akin to what nog642 posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You undesired output came from

```
def output(new_dict, a, b, c, d, e):
    nicer_format = ", ".join("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in new_dict.items())
    return '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(a, b, c, nicer_format, d, e)
```

To get your desired output,

```
def output(new_dict, a, b, c, d, e):
    output_lines = ''
    first = True
    for k, v in new_dict.items():
        if first:
            output_lines += '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}: {}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(a, b, c, k, v, d, e)
            first = False
        else:
            output_lines += '\t\t\t{}: {}\t\t\n'.format(k, v)
    return output_lines
```

Now `output_lines` will have multiple lines, like in your desired output.